# domain-driven design - should each entity have guid?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, guid

I have ID as Guid in Order table and in OrderItem also ID as Guid. So OrderStatus (New / Confirmed / Payed / Sent) should have ID also as Guid?

Comment: Could you explain more, why you have chosen OrderStatus to be an entity?

Comment: All entities would require ID in DDD. But I don't think that order status in your case is an entity. It is order's property. It can be value object too.

Answer (score 0):

In DDD, your domain is composed from mainly two types of classes (they are others, but I'm going to focus on these two to keep it simple):

1. **Entities**: An entity always has an ID, because the equally of an entity is based on his ID (If two entities are of the same types and their IDs are equal, then these entities are equal). A good example of an entity is a person, a person is unique and can't be equivalent by its properties then a  person have an ID and it's an entity.
2. **Value objects**: A value object doesn't have an ID, because the equality of a value object is based on its properties. A good example is an email address. Two email addresses are equal when the domain and the prefix are equal then an email address is a value object.

So you have to determine if OrderStatus is an entity or a value object. If it's an entity then it have an ID.

Hint: Based on your description it looks like it's a value object.